# Custom kernel constraint in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to implement a custom weight constraint for a dense layer.

My weight matrix has shape (588,42). What I want to do is divide the number of rows in sets of 84 and assign to each 84 rows in the matrix the same weight. Same for the next set of 84 but higher value in than the first set etc

So imagine that all my sets of 84 are weighted with a weight named h_i, being i the ith set on the weight matrix. The idea is h_1<=h_2<=...<=h_n. Moreover, I would like the sum of all h's to be 1.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rescale the weight following your logic (I use TF 2.2)

```
class custom(tf.keras.constraints.Constraint):

    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length

    def __call__(self, W):
        w_shape = W.shape
        rep = w_shape[0]/self.length
        w = (np.arange(1,rep+1)/np.arange(1,rep+1).sum()).astype('float32')
        w = tf.reshape(tf.repeat(tf.constant(w), self.length*w_shape[1]), [w_shape[0],w_shape[1]])

        return w*W
```

define model

```
inp = Input(shape=(100))
x = Dense(588)(inp)
out = Dense(42, kernel_constraint=custom(84))(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')
```

dummy train

```
model.fit(np.random.normal(0,1, (10, 100)), np.random.normal(0,1, (10, 42)), epochs=10)
```

I hope this help